# Oracle APEX DISTINCT Label?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

What is going wrong here ?

```
select NULL as "LINK",
       DISTINCT HARDWAREOVERZICHT_STATIC."TOPDESK_vestiging" as "LABEL",
count( ZAM_BUILDING) as "STORK7" 
from HARDWAREOVERZICHT_STATIC 
where Omgeving = 'STORK7'
and "TOPDESK_heeftattentie" = 0
group by HARDWAREOVERZICHT_STATIC."TOPDESK_vestiging",ZAM_BUILDING 
order by HARDWAREOVERZICHT_STATIC."TOPDESK_vestiging" desc
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to every column in your select statement. You've written it like it's a function but it isn't.

Comment: it still doenst work when i delete the distinct it runs bud not the way i want

Comment: how do i fix it then

Comment: Well then that's another issue.  I'd suggest posting your table structure and some sample data, showing what you want as the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is a keyword that follows `SELECT` and applies to all the columns in the clause.  However, it is generally not needed with `group by`:

```
select NULL as "LINK", s."TOPDESK_vestiging" as "LABEL",  
      count( ZAM_BUILDING) as "STORK7"
from HARDWAREOVERZICHT_STATIC s
where Omgeving = 'STORK7' and "TOPDESK_heeftattentie" = 0
group by s."TOPDESK_vestiging"
order by s."TOPDESK_vestiging" desc;
```

I removed `ZAM_BUILDING` from the `group by`.  Otherwise, the `count()` will always be `0` or `1`.  I also added a table alias.

Comment: is there also a possebility to edit the layout because the TOPDESK_VESTIGING NAMES ARE REALLY BIG and they are not displayed on the y label